# C# search query for comma delimited access database field

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using Visual Studio to create a C# program with a query that will search a comma delimited access database field for a value.

For example, the database field for one record could be A,B,C or C,B for another record or A for another record. If txtDept = C, the query would be successful in the first two records but not in the third. This is the code I came up with, but Visual Studio gives me an error on `txtDept` that says `"cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'"`.

Is there a way to split the database field before comparing it to txtDept?

Can anyone help me come up with a valid query please?

```
var courses = from crs in trainingLogDataSet.Course
    where txtDept in crs.Departments
    orderby crs.Date
    select crs;
foreach (var crs in courses)
{
    do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error appears to be coming from your where clause.

`where txtDept in crs.Departments` should be `where crs.Departments.Contains(txtDept)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
var courses = from crs in trainingLogDataSet.Course
                  where crs.Departments.Contains(txtDept)
                  orderby crs.Date
                  select crs
```